# Wordpress PHP Conflicting User Sessions

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using the following function to programmatically login users via the frontend:

```
    function auto_login() {
        $username = $_POST['user'];
        if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
            $user = get_userdatabylogin( $username );
            $user_id = $user->ID;
            wp_set_current_user( $user_id, $user_login );
            wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id );
            do_action( 'wp_login', $user_login );
        }     
    }
    add_action('wp_ajax_auto_login', 'auto_login');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_auto_login', 'auto_login');
```

However one weird issue I've run into is the following scenario:

```
    1. User 1 logs in on PC 1

    2. User 1 email is displayed as logged in in PC 1

    3. User 2 logs in on PC 2

    4. User 1 email is displayed as logged in in PC 2
```

I think this might be due to conflicting sessions but I'm not sure. I've looked up on this for quite a few days on Google yet nothing really came up which helped me.

So my question is, how do I solve this issue of conflicting sessions?

Thanks

Comment: Sessions are "bound" to the computer. If you're using two computers it's not a session problem, but an error in your login process or queries

Comment: Are you using Varnish or NGINX with cache? Or maybe you are caching via apache's htaccess/virtualhost directives?

Comment: Yea basically it seems that I had Page Caching enabled which was causing the users to not log in properly